# Howto use Javafx without opengl?

Tags: java, javafx

I try [JavaFX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) with JDK8.

OpenGL is not installed on my laptop. I don't need it and I suppose [I can use JavaFX without OpenGL](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm).

> Java2D when hardware acceleration is not possible
>
> The fully hardware accelerated path is used when possible, but when it is not available, the Java2D render path is used because the Java2D render path is already distributed in all of the Java Runtime Environments (JREs). This is particularly important when handling 3-D scenes. However, performance is better when the hardware render paths are used.

I just will execute JavaFX Hello World. How ?

When I try I have this message (with *-Dprism.verbose=true* jvm option):

> Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw
> Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
> Using dirty region optimizations
> Not using texture mask for primitives
> Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
> Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
> Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
> Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
> Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
> succeeded.
> GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
> Unrecognized deviceID 0xa16
> X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
> Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
> Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
> Serial number of failed request:  33
> Current serial number in output stream:  34
> Java Result: 1

Why Java try to use OpenGL and not Java2D.

Answer (score 4):

Add the next property:

```
-Dprism.order=j2d
```

Comment: With this pnoperty, the window open \°/